# Change all instances of a word AND update a color with jQuery. Here's what I have at the moment:

Tags: jquery, regex, colors, css-selectors, instances

Change all instances of a word AND update the color of ONLY the changed words with jQuery. Here's what I have at the moment:

```
if($("body").html($("body").html().replace(/Copyright © \d{4}\b/g,"Copyright © 
2018"))){
$(this).css({"color": "red"});
}
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution and my jquery isn't the best at the moment. I tried adding a class to it and then using the class selector to change it, but I didn't know what to attach the class selector to. So to be clear...

I'm looking for all instances of "Copyright © [1234]" and updating it to the current year and then I want to change the color of those specific instances to red.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the text is inside an element like `<p>` or `<h1>` and you can not wrap the match in for example a `<span>` you could use this example. Note that when `Copyright © 2011` is placed directly inside the `<body>` tag, the `<body>` tag will get color red.

Using [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) without anchors will return true if it can find a match in the string. If you want an exact match you could use anchors `^$` to assert the start and the end.

[`^Copyright © \d{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/iGyPnu/1)

If there can be whitespace characters at the start or at the end you could  `\s*`:

[`^\s*Copyright © \d{4}\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/iGyPnu/2)

```js
let pattern = /Copyright © \d{4}\b/;
let currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
$('body').find("*").filter(function() {
  return pattern.test($(this).text());
}).each(function(i, e) {
  $(e).text($(e).text().replace(pattern, "Copyright © " + currentYear));
  $(e).css({
    "color": "red"
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Copyright © 2011</p>
<div><span>Copyright © 2011A</span></div>
<div>test</div>
<div><span>Copyright © 2011</span></div>
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use CSS outside of jQuery in this particular situation. All has to be done within jQuery. And it's only supposed to affect `/Copyright © \d{4}\b/g` format exactly. It's a little contrived, I know... But that's the task. Thanks!

Comment: Oh and it's not supposed to change the element type. For example, if the it's a <p> or an <h1> the output should be the same as when it was evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just one more line of code. Seems obvious now.

https://codepen.io/danielhayespco/pen/qyeagg

```
$("body").html($("body").html().replace(/Copyright © \d{4}\b/g,"Copyright © 2018"));
$("body").find(":contains('Copyright © 2018')").css("color", "red");
```